# Javascript code runs fine on Codesandbox but not on localy or on a webserver

Tags: javascript, camera, codesandbox

I tried to read read QR code thanks to javascript code found in this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-qr-code-reader-mobile-website/)

The code provided by this tutorial works inside the codesandbox linked in the tutorial, however it doesn't work when I tired the same exact code on my laptop or on my remote webserver. I've litteraly copy and paste the code with the same file configuration, filenames ect... but I'm getting the following JS error on my browser :

> SyntaxError: Identifier 'qrcode' has already been declared (at qrCodeScanner.js:1:1)

Since I run the exact same code I d'ont understand what is going on there. Is there something needed on the server side in order to make the code works that is not mentioned in the tutorial ?

If you want to see the code used and see it in action, you can teste the codesandbox instance [there](https://codesandbox.io/embed/ilrm9?codemirror=1).

EDIT

Here's the code I use :
(HMTL)

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>QR Code Scanner</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/style.css" />
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/sitepoint-editors/jsqrcode/master/src/qr_packed.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="container">
      <h1>QR Code Scanner</h1>

      <a id="btn-scan-qr">
        <img src="https://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1499401426qr_icon.svg">
      <a/>

      <canvas hidden="" id="qr-canvas"></canvas>

      <div id="qr-result" hidden="">
        <b>Data:</b> <span id="outputData"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./src/qrCodeScanner.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

(Javascript)

```
const qrcode = window.qrcode;

const video = document.createElement("video");
const canvasElement = document.getElementById("qr-canvas");
const canvas = canvasElement.getContext("2d");

const qrResult = document.getElementById("qr-result");
const outputData = document.getElementById("outputData");
const btnScanQR = document.getElementById("btn-scan-qr");

let scanning = false;

qrcode.callback = res => {
  if (res) {
    outputData.innerText = res;
    scanning = false;

    video.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(track => {
      track.stop();
    });

    qrResult.hidden = false;
    canvasElement.hidden = true;
    btnScanQR.hidden = false;
  }
};

btnScanQR.onclick = () => {
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: "environment" } })
    .then(function(stream) {
      scanning = true;
      qrResult.hidden = true;
      btnScanQR.hidden = true;
      canvasElement.hidden = false;
      video.setAttribute("playsinline", true); // required to tell iOS safari we don't want fullscreen
      video.srcObject = stream;
      video.play();
      tick();
      scan();
    });
};

function tick() {
  canvasElement.height = video.videoHeight;
  canvasElement.width = video.videoWidth;
  canvas.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);

  scanning && requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}

function scan() {
  try {
    qrcode.decode();
  } catch (e) {
    setTimeout(scan, 300);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you import the same library two times?

Comment: We can't see your version of the code, the one that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

The problem is that you are probably using a live server or just opening the html file, but in the sandbox `parcel-bundler` is used. `var qrcode` from the library collides with your `const qrcode`.

### Solutions

#### Type module

Replace

```
<script src="./src/qrCodeScanner.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script type="module" src="./src/qrCodeScanner.js"></script>
```

#### Rename

Change your variable to something else like `const myQrcode`

#### Use a bundler

You can use `parcel-bundler` as in the sandbox or any other that will resolve variable collision for you

Comment: Thanks ! First solution worked fine for me ! Just a side note for anyone reading this post in the future : Due to browser security, the script works either with a localhost service, either with a webserver with HTTPS protocol setup, simple HTTP server will be block by the browser.